# How to use timer in pywin32

Tags: python, pywin32

I want the logging function to run every 1 second using Python and pywin32 timer module. Here is my code

```
import timer    
i = 0
def logging():
    global i
    print(str(i))
    i += 1

timer.set_timer(1000, logging)
```

However I don't see any output on screen. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: No that is not your code. What is the definition of `timer`?  Make a [mcve] and leave the imports in.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I just import timer (from pywin32)

Comment: Yes, so why leave out that line of code?

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'm sorry for this misundertanding. I did mention it in the introduction so I didn't add it in the code. That seems to make some confusion. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Always give a complete example.  It could have been `from pywin32 import timer` for all anyone knows.  An example should be runnable from a simple cut/paste without having to research the imports.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Really appriciate your time and advices! I will remember that when asking a question next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [timer_demo.py](https://github.com/packagecontrol/pywin32/blob/master/st3_windows_x32/win32/Demos/timer_demo.py) (reproduced below).  The `pywin32` timer is based on Windows messages so a message loop needs to be implemented.

```py
# -*- Mode: Python; tab-width: 4 -*-
#

# This module, and the timer.pyd core timer support, were written by
# Sam Rushing (rushing@nightmare.com)

import timer
import time

# Timers are based on Windows messages.  So we need
# to do the event-loop thing!
import win32event, win32gui

# glork holds a simple counter for us.

class glork:

    def __init__ (self, delay=1000, max=10):
        self.x = 0
        self.max = max
        self.id = timer.set_timer (delay, self.increment)
        # Could use the threading module, but this is
        # a win32 extension test after all! :-)
        self.event = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def increment (self, id, time):
        print('x = %d' % self.x)
        self.x = self.x + 1
        # if we've reached the max count,
        # kill off the timer.
        if self.x > self.max:
            # we could have used 'self.id' here, too
            timer.kill_timer (id)
            win32event.SetEvent(self.event)

# create a counter that will count from '1' thru '10', incrementing
# once a second, and then stop.

def demo (delay=1000, stop=10):
    g = glork(delay, stop)
    # Timers are message based - so we need
    # To run a message loop while waiting for our timers
    # to expire.
    start_time = time.time()
    while 1:
        # We can't simply give a timeout of 30 seconds, as
        # we may continouusly be recieving other input messages,
        # and therefore never expire.
        rc = win32event.MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(
                (g.event,), # list of objects
                0, # wait all
                500,  # timeout
                win32event.QS_ALLEVENTS, # type of input
                )
        if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            # Event signalled.
            break
        elif rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0+1:
            # Message waiting.
            if win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages():
                raise RuntimeError("We got an unexpected WM_QUIT message!")
        else:
            # This wait timed-out.
            if time.time()-start_time > 30:
                raise RuntimeError("We timed out waiting for the timers to expire!")

if __name__=='__main__':
    demo()
```

Output (with 1-second delay between lines):

```
x = 0
x = 1
x = 2
x = 3
x = 4
x = 5
x = 6
x = 7
x = 8
x = 9
x = 10
```

Minimal example that will count forever:

```py
import timer
import win32gui
import win32event

i = 0
def logging(timer_id, current_time):
    global i
    print(i)
    i += 1

timer.set_timer(1000, logging)

# The message loop waits for a windows message,
# then dispatches it.  The callback won't run
# without this processing.
while True:
    rc = win32event.MsgWaitForMultipleObjects((), False, win32event.INFINITE, win32event.QS_ALLEVENTS)
    if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        win32gui.PumpWaitingMessages()
```

If you just want a background counter, you could just use a thread:

```py
import threading
import time

def logging():
    i = 0
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        i += 1

threading.Thread(target=logging).start()

# For some foreground activity:
while True:
    print('.', end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(.2)
```

Output:

```
.....0
.....1
.....2      # etc...
```

Comment: I dont really understand how event in that example "interact" with a timer, as its definition and the message loop have no information about the timer?

Comment: The timer is implemented with Windows messages, so you need a standard Windows message loop for them to be processed.

Comment: It's not really clear to me... Can you please make a simple example with the logging function I made above?

Comment: @Joey I added an example eliminating the event that kills the timer.